# How best to store temperature data for different cities?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

It is a little confusing but I will do my best to explain it, I hope it will be fine.

I am trying to create the following functionality in iOS:

I have red button on each row of tableview. The red button is dragged and dropped over the (prototype) tableViewcell and in each row the button will be used. The button text shows the temperature in Fahrenheit. But it changes when tapped so that the color of the button changes to green. And I want the extra functionality at this point; The temperature in Fahrenheit will change into Celcius. (I have the problem on this functionality)

The problem here is that I have a list of tableviewcells (Each is another city), not just one. So I have got that number of buttons and I don't use database to save the temperature data. The data is read through a service and put into an array and transferred to this view by NSUserDefaults.

For example; I have got a list of cities in my tableview. Each is a row and each temperature is put over a red button. Temperature values are the texts of the red buttons.

1. Berlin      45F
2. Istanbul    70F
3. Miami      100F
4. Chicago     30F

...etc.

So for example, when I tap on the button on Berlin row to change the Fahrenheit to Celcius, there is no problem for the first time so I can get the Celcius value for Berlin, no problem. But when I tap it next time to change it to Fahrenheit again, the value does not come correctly. The Fahrenheit value of Berlin is confused with the other values. Because I don't use a database and it does read the value from an array and it doesn't know which value to use. After some clicks, all the Fahrenheit values come to a single value which is the last city's Fahrenheit value (I use the indexPath.row so it gets the last clicked value)

How can I maintain the temperature data for Berlin without using a database so that when I tap that again after tapping the other cities' buttons, it will show me the correct value (45F or the correct Celcius value)?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Show the code you are using now to populate your table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I suggest you use some form of key-based storage (like creating a class "Cities" that stores the temperature, or even storing the city -> temperature key combo in a dictionary), you could read the button text when you click it and convert the value from NSString back to a double or integer.
I assume the function that gets called when you click the button looks something like the one I'm about to write. You can then get the button you clicked and the text it displays like so:

```
- (IBAction)convertTemperature:(id)sender {
    UIButton *myButton = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSString *buttonText = [myButton titleForState:UIControlStateNormal];
    //...
}
```

After this, you just convert the string to get the temperature, convert it and display it back.